# Unexpected character encountered for inner node in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to access the inner nodes of my JSON API.  I am trying to get the values of "TITLE", "TITLE1", and "TITLE2".

This is my API: https://api.myjson.com/bins/ftu3a

When I try to do so I get the following exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].PROJECT', 
line 1, position 13.
```

Code:

```cs
public class Store {
    static WebClient client = new WebClient();

    public static string reply = 
    client.DownloadString("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ftu3a");

    private string TITLE;
    private string PROJECT;

    [JsonProperty("TITLE")]
    public string TITLE1 { get => TITLE; set => TITLE = value; }

    [JsonProperty("PROJECT")]
    public string PROJECT1 { get => PROJECT; set => PROJECT = value; }

    public class StoreCollection {
        private List<Store> store1;
        public List<Store> Store1 { get => store1; set => store1 = value; }
    }
}

public class Program : Store {
    public void GetValues() {
        var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Store>>(reply);
        foreach (var item in stuff) {
            Console.WriteLine(item); Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Program P1 = new Program();
        P1.GetValues();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the JSON you provided it seems PROJECT would require a class of itself with properties TITLE1/TITTLE2/TITLE, also it just seems badly formed in general since it has a random value "11" sitting on it's own. Might be worth creating dummy value in your class then use JsonConvert to get the sample text.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `PROJECT` is not a string. It is another object with title properties.

So it would seem your class properties do not match what you're attempting to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value "11" can not be cast to a property name.

[{"PROJECT":{**"11"**:{"TITLE":"A","TITLE1":"B","TITLE2":"C"}}}]

I tried to refactor your code, and you can do like this. Your class structure did not following JSON structure.

```
public class STORE
    {
        public string TITLE { get; set; }
        public string TITLE1 { get; set; }
        public string TITLE2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class PROJECT
    {
        public STORE STORE { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public PROJECT PROJECT { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        public void GetValues()
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            string reply =
                client.DownloadString("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ftu3a");
            reply = reply.Replace("11", "STORE");

            var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(reply);


            foreach (var item in stuff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item); Console.Read();
            }

        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Program P1 = new Program();
            P1.GetValues();
        }
    }
```